# C# Invoke an event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have created this program here to demonstrate what i am trying to do. You can see that all the code is already written except the line where the `_OnSell` event should be invoked. (Line 21~)

```
using System;

namespace example
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Price;
        public string ModelName;
        private Boolean Sold;
        public delegate void SellEventHandler(string str);
        public event SellEventHandler _OnSell;
        public Boolean _Sold
        {
            get { return Sold; }
            set
            {
                Sold = value;
                if (Sold == true)
                {
                    // INVOKE _OnSell EVENT HERE !!
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnSell(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("library stuff");
        }

        public Car(int price, string modelname)
        {
            Price = price;
            ModelName = modelname;
            Sold = false;
            _OnSell = OnSell;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Program p1 = new Program();
            Car _car = new Car(6000, "audi");
            _car._OnSell += p1.Car_OnSell;
            _car._Sold = Console.ReadLine() == "true" ? true : false;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void Car_OnSell(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("user stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to invoke the event `_car._OnSell` whenever the value `_car._Sold` is changed. How can i do that in C# ?

Comment: Just call `OnSell(..)` - which should in turn invoke the event? See [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @user2864740 can you provide the exact code ? , i have already seen this, this is how i got to this stage in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thus, following the example provided, the code would look like the following.

Note the name changes for a cleaner public API and de facto consistency and naming standards.

```
public class Car
{
    // Note use of `sender` convention
    public delegate void SoldEventHandler(object sender, string str);

    // Events normally do not have the `On` prefix, also the event
    // name is normally the sense-correct verb such as `Sold` or `Selling`.
    public event SoldEventHandler Sold;

    private bool _isSold;
    public bool IsSold
    {
        get { return _isSold; }
        set
        {
            if (value && !_isSold) {
               // Only sell when false -> true
               OnSold("whatever string it is supposed to be");
            }
            _isSold = value;
        }
    }

    // "Typically, to raise an event, you add a method that is marked as protected and virtual.
    //  .. Name this method OnEventName; for example, OnDataReceived."
    public virtual void OnSold(string str)
    {
        // Follow the conventions in the link - ask on SO as to why the local
        // variable and check for null are important/necessary.
        var handler = Sold;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, str);
        }
    }

// ..

    _car.Sold += p1.Car_OnSell;
    _car.IsSold += Console.ReadLine() == "true" ? true : false;
```

In most cases I would recommend having the event take `(object sender, EventArgs args)` as it makes future changes to the event much more flexible - this is *also* discussed in the link.

Comment: can i ask about the `cleaner public API` when do you actually use `_` ? is it only in private variables ?

Comment: @Shiro I only use `_` in private variables, yes. There is some debate if it should be `privateVariable` or `_privateVarible` or `m_privateVariable`, etc, but as long as such is _not_ exposed as part of the public/internal API all of said conventions are .. private conventions. I prefer `_privateVariable` because it helps me clearly identify such (but I don't use this convention for private methods, properties, so..)

Comment: thats reasonable, so the right way is not use `_` on any public variables/methods .  thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the links offered by commenters (but unfortunately not explained in the first answer that was posted), you need to change your code so that it looks more like this:

```
public Boolean _Sold
{
    get { return Sold; }
    set
    {
        Sold = value;
        if (Sold)
        {
            OnSell("your string here");
        }
    }
}

public void OnSell(string str)
{
    SellEventHandler handler = _OnSell;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(str);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("library stuff");
}
```

The above will work. However, it's worth noting that you're deviating from the normal .NET event-handling idioms in a couple of important ways:

1. Your event delegate does not follow the `EventHandler<T>` structure. The normal .NET method signature offers two advantages: identification of the sender, and a standardized `EventArgs` data structure on which to base your event arguments.
2. You are raising the event only when the property is set to `true`. More typical, and frankly more useful, is a "changed" event. E.g. `SoldChanged`, which would be raised any time the value of the `Sold` property was changed.

One of the nicer benefits of following the standard event-handling idioms is that your class will work with most if not all of the common data binding implementations in .NET. The way you have it implemented here, your event is very limited in the way it can be used. That might be fine in this scenario, but as a general rule it's so easy to provide more flexible implementation, you might as well get in the habit of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_OnSell( "some message" );
```

Comment: While a reasonable first step, this still won't call the `_OnSell` event.

Comment: Ref. [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - calling `OnSell` initially is "good accepted practice", just need to wire that up as appropriate. Note that the null check shown (and assignment of the handler to a temporary variable) are important to correctly dispatch standard .NET/C# events.

Comment: i dont want only to call `_OnSell( "some message" );`  method . i also need to call `Car_OnSell` function. this is the point of the event itsself. i ll try and follow the link in the comments, with a clear head

Comment: If you call _OnSell it fill fire OnSell method, since you added it in constructor, and also Car_OnSell will be called since you added method to event after initialization. Just tested it :)

Comment: @TheLittleHawk thats actually correct, then what did @user2864740 meant by "this still won't call the `_OnSell` event" ? im confused

Comment: `public event SellEventHandler _OnSell;` and `_OnSell` (the _event_) is not `OnSell` (the _method_). You call the event by [__following the instructions in the link__](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after "The following example shows how to declare an event named ThresholdReached. The event is associated with the EventHandler delegate and raised in a method named OnThresholdReached". This will in turn call the event listeners that have been registered.

Comment: @user2864740 correct, it is `OnSell` followed by `Car_OnSell` , am i right ?

Comment: @Shiro No, you __never__ call `Car_OnSell` from the Car class. You raise the `_OnSell` _event_ which in turns call the attached handlers. The correct way to call the event handler is shown in the link. This is normally done from the companion `OnXYZ` _method_.

Comment: I would keep `OnSell` .. refer to the link. Although it would be nicest to give different names so underscores are not used. For instance, the _method_ could be `OnSold` and the _event_ would be `Sold`.

Comment: i meant in this specific case, it happens to be `Car_OnSell` so the code of `OnSell` + `Car_OnSell` is called, if you follow the answer from @TheLittleHawk , i am trying to grasp the basics of creating a library, as for the link, i will totally read it in depth a bit later, english is not my first language, thank you for it